# Generating Thread Dump on Sun JDK with Timestamp

Tags: java, sun, thread-dump

I need to generate the Thread dumps on Sun Solaris machine for my application which is using Sun's Java5. 
I am generating Thread Dump using the following command:

```
kill -QUIT pid
```

But the thread dumps generated using this does not log the timestamp when the dump has been taken.
This is creating problem if I take multiple thread dumps.

Can you please suggest how to get the timestamp with the thread dumps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VisualVM utility provided in JDK 6.0. You can connect to your Java5 application using visualvm and can get/compare thread dump, memory dump etc.

Comment: Does it mean that VisualVM will help in generating dumps with Timestamp logged into the dumps?

Comment: Yes. You can also, compare two dumps.